# Adding variant to a Material-UI button with a custom component gives typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

I made a custom Link component based on [this example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/src/Link.js). Here's the code:

```js
import classNames from 'classnames';
import {forwardRef} from 'react';
import MuiLink, {LinkProps as MuiLinkProps} from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import NextLink, {LinkProps as NextLinkProps} from 'next/link';
import isString from 'lodash/isString';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

import assert from '@todo/lib/assert';

type SelectedNextLinkProps = Pick<NextLinkProps, 'as' | 'href'>;
type SelectedMuiLinkProps = Omit<MuiLinkProps, 'href'>;

type ComposedLinkProps = Omit<SelectedMuiLinkProps, 'className'> & SelectedNextLinkProps;

const ComposedLink = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, ComposedLinkProps>((props, ref): JSX.Element => {
  const {as, href, ...other} = props;
  return (
    <NextLink as={as} href={href}>
      <a ref={ref} {...other} />
    </NextLink>
  );
});
ComposedLink.displayName = 'ComposedLink';

type LinkProps = SelectedMuiLinkProps & SelectedNextLinkProps & {activeClassName?: string};

const Link = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>((props, ref): JSX.Element => {
  const {activeClassName: _, className, href, underline = 'none', ...other} = props;
  let {activeClassName} = props;

  const router = useRouter();

  const pathname = isString(href) ? href : href.pathname;
  assert(isString(pathname), 'Link requires a valid href');
  if (pathname !== router.pathname) {
    activeClassName = undefined;
  }

  return (
    <MuiLink
      className={classNames(className, activeClassName)}
      component={ComposedLink}
      href={pathname}
      ref={ref}
      underline={underline}
      {...other}
    />
  );
});
Link.displayName = 'Link';

export default Link;
```

I can use it in a button like so:

```
<Button color="secondary" component={Link} href="/signup">
  Sign up
</Button>
```

But when I add a variant prop:

```
<Button color="secondary" component={Link} href="/signup" variant="contained">
  Sign up
</Button>
```

I get indecipherable typescript errors:

```
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<LinkProps, "color" | "display" | "translate" | "hidden" | "style" | "underline" | "as" | "href" | "className" | "classes" | "innerRef" | ... 265 more ... | "activeClassName"> & RefAttributes<...>>; href: string; color: "secondary"; variant: "contained"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<LinkProps, "color" | "display" | "translate" | "hidden" | "style" | "underline" | "as" | "href" | "className" | "classes" | "innerRef" | "slot" | ... 264 more ... | "activeClassName"> & RefAttributes<...>>; } & { ...; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<LinkProps, "color" | "display" | "translate" | "hidden" | "style" | "underline" | "as" | "href" | "className" | "classes" | "innerRef" | ... 265 more ... | "activeClassName"> & RefAttributes<...>>; href: string; color: "secondary"; variant: "contained"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.

  12 |       Sign in
  13 |     </Button>
> 14 |     <Button component={Link} href="/signup" color="secondary" variant="contained">
     |     ^
  15 |       Sign up
  16 |     </Button>
  17 |   </ButtonGroup>
```

My best guess is that variant is getting passed to my custom Link component (on the way to the inner anchor? I have no idea) and since it's not in props, typescript blows up. Can anyone tell me what's going on here? And how I can fix it?

One other interesting thing that I noticed after posting: tsc error out, but I'm using babel to do the actual build and babel compiles it successfully and it works. So, it appears to be solely a typing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling, it appears this is just a bug in Material-UI that won't be backported to 4.x: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/22452 I would accept a workaround if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

This question goes into the rabbithole of material-ui, so its fine if you aren't interested, or can't understand.

In material ui, Buttonbase is root component of Button component, by default.
You have overwritten it to your custom component Link, whose type (unlike ButtonBase) does not allow "variant" as its prop.

This is why type issue is occuring.

Solution? let Link component accept variant as props. Maybe add it to LinkProps. Its your choice

Sources
https://material-ui.com/guides/api/#spread
https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Comment: I tried adding variant to both LinkProps and ComposedLinkProps and I still get the same error.

Comment: @btmorex How did you do it? you add variant as type string? I think it should be more specific

Comment: I added it like this `type LinkProps = SelectedMuiLinkProps & SelectedNextLinkProps & {activeClassName?: string; variant?: 'text' | 'outlined' | 'contained'};`